# Maintaining user controls public property state across postbacks

Tags: asp.net, properties, user-controls, session-state

I have a user control that only displays customer information on each .aspx page in my application. That user controls contains public properties for customer information those are set from .aspx page (say page1.aspx) OnLoad event and displays information in that user control. Now from this page1.aspx, redirects to page2.aspx but couldn't able to display information in page2.aspx usercontrol (the values are lost after postback). I could maintain user control's properties state by using session in each proprty of control and can access in all the pages, but  sessions would be expensive ways to do that. Please give me another better solution about this, so that i can maintain user controls properties value across postbacks.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

The information is not lost in PostBack as the Page2.aspx gets a seperate GET request after doing a redirection from Page1.aspx

There are below ways by which you can do state management

1. Session State
2. Application state
3. View State
4. Cookies
5. Query string
6. HTML Web storage

Session state is what seems to be the logical choice for your scenario,  As application state would affect the data for all the users who are logged in. Viewstate will be lost once we do a Redirection. For cookies there would be problems with size limit and you need to clear the data stored in cookies. Also, you should be encrypting the data stored there. Query strings are easy to be tampered & is not reliable. HTML Web storage is available only in latest browsers and hence browser compatibility would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

One other possible answer - you could use CrossPagePostback.  This allows Page2 to automatically detect data passed from Page1.  You'd have to do this on the page's load event.

A redirect will always take you to another page, and this will always lose any state attached to the first page.  The only way you can maintain state like this is by not using a web application!

Answer (score 0):

It's never really a good idea to keep the user information in a session and as little as possible in a cookie.  Neither are secure and as you can see have some state baggage that seldom justifies it's use.

I recommend going back to the drawing board and designing a solution that keeps the information in a database obviously on the server; even if the record is purged at the end of the transaction.  Watch that table and you'll be surprised how many sessions are dropped and never reach the "official" end of the transaction.